# jqGrid Multiple row editing doesn't save to database in iOS7

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, rows, multi-select

I use jqgrid in my web application. Using iOS 7, when I select all rows in a jqgrid table and try to save my edits into the database, it doesn't save.
If I just edit one row and then save and then edit another row - basically if I edit one row at a time - then it works. Just multiple row editing doesn't work. And it only doens't work on iOS 7.

I have already seen this post: http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=13688
and I have updated my jqgrid to the latest release (4.5.4) and I am still having this same problem on iOS 7.

Here is the javascript for submit the records:

```
function submitChange(tabId) {
 if (!submitFlag) return;
 var records=[];
 var $t = $("#" + tabId);
 var selectedIds = $t.jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');
 var postData = $t.jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
 if (selectedIds.length > 0) {
  for (var i=0; i < selectedIds.length; i++){
   updatedList[selectedIds[i]] = composeEditedRecord(selectedIds[i]);  //Put edited record into updatedList
  }
 } else {
  alert($T('missing.msg'));
  return;
 }
 var z = 0;
 for (var key in updatedList) {
  if (typeof(updatedList[key].endDate) != 'undefined'
    && typeof(updatedList[key].endTypeId) != 'undefined') {
   records[z] = updatedList[key];
   z++;
  } else {
   alert($T('missing.msg'));
   return;
  }
 }

 if (records.length < $t.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records')) {
  alert($T('missing.msg'));
  return;
 }
 $.extend(postData, {'updatedList': JSON.stringify(records)});

 $.post('mse/end', postData, function(data) {

  history.go(-1);
 });
}
```

Also the jquery version is 1.5.1.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" media="screen" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.custom.css" media="screen" />


<script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="jquery/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="jquery/plugins/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="jquery/plugins/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is composeEditedRecord function:

```
function composeEditedRecord(id) {
 var tmp = getEditableCells('mseTableEnd', id);
 var editedRecord = updatedList[id];
 if (!editedRecord) {
  editedRecord = {};
  editedRecord['id'] = id;
 }
 for (var key in tmp) {
  if (key == 'tag')
   editedRecord['TagPattern'] = tmp[key];
  else
   editedRecord[key] = tmp[key];
 }

 return editedRecord;
}
```

Here is definition of jqGrid:

```
$("#mseTableEnd").jqGrid({
        url: 'mse/list.json',
        sortname: 'guisid',
        colNames: mse.columnDisplayNames,
        colModel: mse.colModelDef,
        postData: filterValues,
        onSelectRow: function(id,status){
         if(status == true) {
    $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
    $('#jqg_mseTableEnd_' + id).focus();
   } else if(status == false) {
    var tmp = getEditableCells('mseTableEnd', id);
       var record = composeEditedRecord(id);
       updatedList[id] = record; //Put edited record into updatedList when unchecked
       $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('restoreRow',id);
       $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('setRowData',id, tmp);
   }

  },
  onSelectAll: function(aRowids, status) {
   if (status){
        for (var i = 0; i < aRowids.length; i++)
         $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('editRow',aRowids[i],true);
        $('#jqg_mseTableEnd_' + aRowids[i-1]).focus();
       } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < aRowids.length; i++) {
         var tmp = getEditableCells('mseTableEnd', aRowids[i]);
         var record = composeEditedRecord(aRowids[i]);
              updatedList[aRowids[i]] = record; //Put edited record into updatedList when unchecked
         $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('restoreRow',aRowids[i]);
         $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('setRowData',aRowids[i], tmp);
        }
       }
  },
  gridComplete: function() {

   $("#mseTableEnd").setColProp('tag',{editable:false});   
     var columnsToHide = [];
   for (var i = 0; i <mse.colModelDef.length; i++) {
    if (i > 12) columnsToHide.push(mse.colModelDef[i].name);
   }
   columnsToHide.push('generation');
   $("#mseTableEnd").jqGrid('hideCol', columnsToHide);
   $("#mseTableEnd").jqGrid('showCol', ['enddate' 'comment']);  
  },
            loadComplete: function() { 
         var ids = $('#mseTableEnd').jqGrid('getDataIDs');
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
       $('#mseTableEnd').setSelection(ids[i]); // All selected by default
             $('#'+ids[i]+' a').click(function(e) {
                 var myHash = e.currentTarget.hash;     // string like "#?id=0"
                 if (myHash.substring(0,5) === '#?id=') {
                     var id = myHash.substring(5,myHash.length); // getting row Id
                     var url = appContext.contextPath + '/mse/edit.do?mseId=' + id;
            hasPermissionByIds('Mse', id, 1, gotoPage, url);
                 }
                 e.preventDefault();
             });
         }
       }
    });
```

Here is getEditableCells function:

```
function getEditableCells(tabId, rowId) {
 var $t = $("#" + tabId);
 var ind = $t.jqGrid("getInd",rowId,true);
 var cm, nm, tmp={};

 $("td",ind).each(function(i) {
  cm = $t.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel')[i];
  nm = cm.name;
  if ( nm != 'cb' && nm != 'subgrid' && cm.editable===true && nm != 'rn') {
   if (cm.edittype == "text") {
    if ($("input, textarea",this).length > 0)
     tmp[nm]=$("input, textarea",this).val();
    else {
     var rowData = $t.jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
     tmp[nm]=rowData[nm];
    }
   }
  }
 });
 return tmp;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: jqGrid don't have the feature saving of multiple lines in the database. So you should append the text of your question with JavaScript code which shows what you do exactly.

Comment: The code don't contain the definition of jqGrid. It's unclear which `datatype` you use and whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. It's also unclear which editing mode you use. Moreover you use `composeEditedRecord` function and `updatedList` variable which are not defined in the posted code. Could you extend the code posted?

Comment: The code which you post still contain a lot of unclear things. I asked you to include the code which shows how you detect edited rows. Now the part in in another undefined function `getEditableCells`. **You don't need to post all your code**. Debugging of your code is your problem. You should prepare small example which reproduce the problem where you have problems. For example which relation has hiding of some columns in `gridComplete`? You post the code with `colModel: mse.colModelDef, postData: filterValues` which provide no information, but use names of some columns in the code.

Comment: You code contains long code with a lot of references (`endDate` and `endTypeId`) to unclear column names. You wrote about problems with saving of rows in database on iOS 7, but you just not verified whether `updatedList` is filled or not. You use very old version of jQuery (1.5.1) and write nothing about tests with more resent versions (like 1.10.2 or 2.0.3) and nothing about tests on other OS and web browsers. Sory, but you should better prepare your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your helps. 
I put getEditableCells function in the post.

we have found the issue to be with these lines in getEditableCells function:

```
if ($("input, textarea",this).length > 0)
 tmp[nm]=$("input, textarea",this).val();
```

If we change the text to this:

```
if ($("input",this).val().length > 0)
 tmp[nm]=$("input",this).val();
```

then it fixes the issue but causes the html to be inserted into the text field in the grid table when I unselect and re-select the checkbox. Perhaps there is something wrong with my jquery syntax?